# ActiveX alternative to save Outlook signature

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, outlook, activex, microsoft-edge

In our company we have a little web application that allows employees to create their e-mail signature, showing them a live preview of what it will look like. They can then directly "save" the signature into their Outlook Signatures.

The "save" feature is implemented via the Microsoft Proprietary "File System Object" ActiveX component:

```
new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")**
```

1. create the signature files (.html, .txt, .rtf)
2. copy the files in Outlook's signature folder on the user's filesystem (%userprofile%\AppData.W7\Microsoft\Signatures)

As we are migrating to Windows 10, our default browser will be Edge. As far as i know it is not possible to use ActiveX in Edge, does anyone know another alternative in order to keep this "save" feature? Or does anyone know some kind of workaround?

All ideas/suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably crock something together by using `document.execCommand( 'saveAs', ...,...);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand but it won't be pretty, since this is one of the reasons why ActiveX is no longer supported. Websites should not have access to the hard drive of the user.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this as access to the file system is explicitly prohibited by browsers.

Comment: @Shilly That doesn't expose a 'saveAs' command.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Ah ofcourse. `saveAs` is Internet Explorer only. Didn't think about that. Maybe a data url pointing to a blob? Upload the files to a server somewhere and download?

Comment: @Shilly i could just trigger a download in JS using [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) - but then the users will still have to copy those files (.html, .txt, . rtf) manually in their signature folder. I was more looking for a kind of "communication" with Outlook; allowing to communicate with some components. I know it's possible to open an application from the browser, thats what Spotify, Slack, uTorrent, etc does for example.

Comment: Just create a function server side,. If using node.js for example, this would be pretty simple to do..   If using IIS, ASP.net, I assume would be pretty easy too.  Another idea, If this is all local to users machine, you could maybe create your app using https://electronjs.org/

Comment: @Keith How can you create a server-side function that will copy a file to a specific path on the user's system?

Comment: That's why I also pointed out using Electron..  Electron apps will have access to the users file-system.  ps.  With the correct security setup, it's also possible to copy files from a server to a client PC,..

Comment: There is nothing you can do - Edge would not let a script programmatically access an arbitrary file/folder on the file system. This is by design.